# Unknown variables in SPYDER varable explorer

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am currently using Spyder 5 as python editor and some unknown variables appear in the variable explorer which are some kind of parameters. Does anybody know how to get rid of them? The image below depicts my problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you use `from numpy import *`?

Comment: No, I am just opening the editor and that is what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

From Spyder, go to **Preferences>Variable explorer** and pick *Exclude private references, Exclude unsupported data types and Exclude callable and modules.*

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by going into **Preferences** > **IPython Console** > **Graphics** and turning off: *Automatically load Pylab and Numpy modules*